# Ubuntu 20.04 wired ethernet disappeared

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 and my ethernet disappeared.

There was no updated and I haven't touched the settings. The disappearance happened between two proper boot ups of the system (worked - switched off properly, in the evening switched on, no ethernet at all).

`ifconfig -a` shows only `lo` and `wlp0s20f3`.
Same for `ip link show`.

Running `sudo lshw -c network` only shows the wireless.

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

The only network related entry in `lscpi -nnk` is the wifi:

```
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Same for `netstat -i`.

Restarting with `nmcli` did not help.

The machine is an Acer Swift 3 laptop.
The connection point and ethernet cable are OK, verified with another machine.

Anybody, has an idea what could have happened?
Thank you!

Comment: Does it appear here? `lspci -nnk` Please redact all of the entries not related to networking.

Comment: Thank you - `lspci -nnk` only lists the wifi not the ethernet (I've added this information to the question now). Could it be a hardware failure?

Comment: I suspect that the ethernet device has failed electrically. Sorry.